# How to implement debounce in typeahead.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js, debouncing

I am writing a search functionality using typeahead.js. I am trying to figure out how debounce can be implemented for the search feature. I went through the typeahead docs, but I couldn't find any relevant information. How to implement the debounce in typeahead? The code is shown below.

```js
$('input.typeahead').typeahead({
  name: 'movies',
  remote: 'http://localhost:3000/searchMovie?key=%QUERY',
  limit: 10
});
```

Comment: Javascript typehead using debounce: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/175434/javascript-typehead-using-debounce

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bloodhound with twitter's typeahead.js library, there is a native option for debouncing the input for the remote lookup.
[bloodhound remote twitter typeahead doc on github](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md#remote)

```
var my_bloodhound = new Bloodhound({
    name : 'search_filter_' + my_filter,
    datumTokenizer : Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
    queryTokenizer : Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    limit : 20,
    prefetch : {
        url : '/my_search.php?filter=' + my_filter,
        filter : myFilterSearchTypeaheadResponse
    },
    remote : {
        wildcard : 'LOOKUP',
        url : '/my_search.php?filter=' + my_filter + '&query=LOOKUP',
        rateLimitBy : 'debounce',
        rateLimitWait : 600,
        filter : myFilterSearchTypeaheadResponse
    }
});
my_bloodhound.clearPrefetchCache();
my_bloodhound.clearRemoteCache();
my_bloodhound.initialize();
```